# Filtering a DataTable by button / one click (R Flexdashboard)

Tags: r, datatables, flexdashboard

I am using DT::datatable in a Flexdashboard to provide some monthly KPIs for about 100 different countries. Five of them are of special interest to some of the dashboard’s users, so I am searching for a solution to easily filter on those countries.

My idea was to generate a button next to the Export Buttons that will filter the data on only those five rows. Clicking it again would most perfectly show the original table again.
I found that there is a possibility to specify [custom buttons](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/custom.html) but still I have no clue how to tackle my problem with this.

Here is a tiny example of the table I get so far:

```
# Random Data Frame
df <- data.frame(Country = paste("Country", 1:100, sep = "_"), 
                 Revenue = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 5000, sd = 2000))

# Data Table used in Dashboard
datatable(df, class = "hover", rownames = FALSE , extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
  pageLength = 5,
  responsive = TRUE,
  dom = 'Bftip',
  buttons = c('copy', 'csv'),
  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = "_all"))
)) %>% formatCurrency(columns = "Revenue")
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a reproducible example in Shiny as I do not think what you are trying to do is feasible in a static document. I assume you have set `runtime: shiny`.

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

countries <- data.frame(
  cns = LETTERS,
  value = runif(26, 1, 4)
)

TOP5 <- c("A", "B", "X", "Y", "Z")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("filter", "Filter countries of interest"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$table <- renderDT({

    sel <- if(input$filter %% 2 == 0) countries$cns else TOP5

    countries %>% 
      filter(cns %in% sel) %>% 
      datatable()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly fine in a Shiny environment. Too bad it's not feasible in a static document because unfortunately my dashboard is static. The solution I chose now is to add a hidden variable that marks all the countries of interest with a specific value, which then can be used for filtering via the search console.

Comment: That is how I'd do it in a static document too.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `shinyApp` embedded  within your `flexdashboard` file.

Note in Your YAML (front matter) you need to set: `runtime: shiny`

### Your Key Pieces of Code are:

**Drop Down Selection Code in the UI**

`Choices` you could specify as the FIVE countries of interest for your team.

```
  # Input: Choose dataset ----
  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a Country",
              choices = as.character(unique(df$Country)))
```

**Download Button**

On the server side the logic is applied to only download the filtered data.

```
  # Button
  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
```

> **Reactive Component**
> *This is important as it allows for the data to be dynamically filtered based on the input selection of the user.*

```
  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
      df %>% filter(Country ==input$dataset)
  })
```

**Finally this allows you to download the filtered data**

```
  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(as.character(input$dataset), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
```

---

> Useful Links

[Shiny App Example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-download.html)

[Using Shiny in Flex Dashboards](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html)

### FULL *.Rmd Code Below

````
---
title: "Filter Data"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
# load data in 'global' chunk so it can be shared by all users of the dashboard
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
# Random Data Frame
df <- data.frame(Country = paste("Country", 1:100, sep = "_"), 
                 Revenue = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 5000, sd = 2000))
```

To learn more, see [Interactive Documents](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html).

## Inputs and Outputs

You can embed Shiny inputs and outputs in your document. Outputs are automatically updated whenever inputs change.  This demonstrates how a standard R plot can be made interactive by wrapping it in the Shiny `renderPlot` function. The `selectInput` and `sliderInput` functions create the input widgets used to drive the plot.

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Downloading Data"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a Country",
                  choices = as.character(unique(df$Country))),
      
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput("table")
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to display and download selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
      df %>% filter(Country ==input$dataset)
  })
  
  # Table of selected dataset ----
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })
  
  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(as.character(input$dataset), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}
# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```
````